# Problems with unmet dependencies

Tags: dependencies

I have tried lots of things I found on this website and others and i just can't get this to go away. This is what happens when I try to install anything:

```
rw@rw:~$ sudo apt install macchanger
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1 : Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
          Depends: libglx0 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.2) but 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libgl1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: You haven't told us your release, but I'll guess 18.04 LTS. Have you tried the suggested --fix-broken solution? though https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libgl1 and https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libglvnd0 make it look like your software [repo] lists are out of date (ie. a `sudo apt update` may fix it), or you are using a out-of-date or poorly maintained mirror (a `apt-cache policy` of one of the packages such as `libgldn0` would show your source) so I'd check that next.  I'd need to know your mirror to look it up for you.

Comment: Run: `sudo apt clean; sudo apt update; sudo apt -f install` and then follow the instructions listed in the following answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/230958/167115

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: You usually just need to install the dependency packages one by one until they have all been satisfied. Please let us know if the solution does not work for you. If it does not work, please tell us why. Thanks!

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy macchanger libglvnd0 libglx0`. It seems that you have not enabled *bionic-updates* pocket. 
Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Looks like a classic version conflict: A requires 2.2, B requires 2.3, no compromise possible. Usually caused by an unwise choice of PPA or other non-Ubuntu source or software. The usual solution is to uninstall the non-Ubuntu software, delete the non-Ubuntu deb packages from your system, and delete the non-Ubuntu source.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep xserver` please. edit your question for output.